# Vue.js environment variables without vue-cli

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

What is the best way to load environment variables for Vue.js app without using vue-cli? In vue-cli way you just update the .env files and those variables should be available in Vue.js app like this: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#example-staging-mode

I am using Symfony Webpack Encore and have no vue-cli installed, how could I pass my environment variables into entire Vue application?

Comment: There's no 'best' way. Vue CLI uses `dotenv` package. You could do that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently this looks like a decent way to load the configs: https://github.com/symfony/webpack-encore/issues/567

First install the dotenv package and then use this on my webpack.config.js:

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');

.configureDefinePlugin(options => {
    const dotenvOptions = {};
    const envConfigPath = `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`;

    if (fs.existsSync(envConfigPath)) dotenvOptions.path = envConfigPath;

    const env = dotenv.config(dotenvOptions);

    if (env.error) {
        throw env.error;
    }

    options['process.env'].PMP_API_BASE_URI = JSON.stringify(env.parsed.PMP_API_BASE_URI);
})
```

If .env.dev.local is needed then provide NODE_ENV=dev.local while running npm run build command.

Answer (score 0):

just create a `.env` file and create you variable like this `VUE_APP_XXXXX`

you notice the `VUE_APP` make sure all variable has the `VUE_APP` prefix like.

`VUE_APP_API_URL`

for development `.env.development`.

for production `.env.production`

Comment: This works only on vue-cli. Already tried it and all these variables is undefined in frontend side.

Comment: oh...

sorry..

will make more researchs for you